# gynecological or gynecologic?

Tags: word-choice, ic-ical

I often write medical copy and have always used 'gynecologic' as the descriptor, as in 'gynecologic oncologist' or 'gynecologic disorders.'
However, I am editing something where the writer uses 'gynecological' in the same way, and cannot seem to find the rule that says that is incorrect.
Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 5):

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gynecology) gives both *gynecologic* and *gynecological* as an adjective. Therefore, whether you use one or the other is at your discretion, but I would advise being consistent with your decision.

However, the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/82853) recognizes only *gynaecological* (note the added *a*), which suggests that *gynecologic* (or *gynaecologic*) is the nonstandard form of the word in British English.

Note that, in cases such as these where you are writing for a particular department or publication, it is important to ask the person(s) whom you are writing for which spelling is preferred.

Comment: And, if you are submitting to or writing for a particular professional organization, inquire whether they have a preference or an available style or vocabulary sheet.

Comment: Thanks guys! I checked the hospital's department name: Gynecologic Oncology, and am going to use that. Appreciated!

Comment: I wonder if this is a US-UK difference. I've never ever seen *gynecologic,* at all. It's always *gynaecological* (and with the extra *a*).

Comment: @AndrewLeach I actually looked for both words in the OED, and only *gynaecological* is mentioned.

Comment: Do you actually mean the OED, or the online-available ODO? There's a big difference.

Comment: I mean oed.com.

Comment: @Jake You should add that to your answer.